# AngularJS: Retrieve Element Name from Directive

Tags: angularjs

I have spent some time looking for this but I haven't found anything.

I have the following

**HTML file**:

```
<my-directive name="someName" id="someId" method="somemethod">
    sometext
</my-directive>
```

**My directive**:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: "example.html",

    transclude: true, 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs)
   {
       alert(element.name);  //Used for testing, Not working
   }
  };
});
```

I am trying to access the element parameters in the directive (name, method, id) but I am unable to figure out how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it should be `app.directive` instead of `app.registerDirective`

Comment: `attrs` - third parameter in link function, that's where element attributes are

Comment: remove the $ sign from the alert statement

Comment: Questions has been modified with suggestions.  @doodeec Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at this [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WyiUpzrz9tQChV5cl9qF?p=preview)

You have the attrs as parameter inside the link function. Use that instead of the element.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.result = attrs['name'];
}
```

You are also using transclusion, but you haven't defined a "ng-transclude" attribute in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Using an alert for testing is very bad practice. You should be writing an assertion that specifically looks for the attribute you want (name in this case) and verifying that it is what you expect it to be. As commenter doodeec above said, you'll find the value you need under attrs.name. References to the element may also need to be element[0] to ensure that you do not get an undefined or null value. Lastly, you have your directive binding to both element and attribute, which seems to be a less than optimal situation. Were I you, I would bind to one or the other, but not both. It'll make for cleaner code in both places and remove some spaghetti.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  I'm new to Angular.  I will bind to only one in the future to help keep everything clean :)